# RegEx Pattern: extracting phonenumbers from a text block

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I'm trying to get all the phone numbers from a string.

Input string:

```
Antoine Smith 911 839 7393 9118582588 91145MAURY Bob Smith
```

I want to get the three phones numbers: `911 839 7393` `9118582588` `91145MAURY`

The regex I'm using.

```
[a-zA-Z]*([0-9]( |-)?)?(\(?[0-9]{3}\)?|[0-9]{3})( |-)?([0-9]{3}( |-)?[0-9]{4}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{7})+
```

However this doesn't work.

If I just put in the phrase : "911 839 7393 9118582588 91145MAURY Bob Smith" then the regex returns the phone numbers.

What regex should I be using?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the area code will never be letters and spaces are the only punctuation to account for, this will work `\d{3} ?\w{3} ?\w{4}`.

Comment: Very nice answer +1. I like it more than mine :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
(\d{3}\s?\d{3}\s?\d{4})|(\d{5}\w{5})
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/sS0xK5/1)**

[image]

Btw, the regex can be shortened a little to:

```
((?:\d{3}\s?){2}\d{4})|(\d{5}\w{5})
```

Comment: I can match the phone numbers it's what happens when you precede them with "Antoine Smith". My latest version of the pattern is: (.*([0-9]( |-)?)?(\(?[0-9]{3}\)?|[0-9]{3})( |-)?([0-9]{3}( |-)?[0-9]{4}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{7}))* It gets past the Antoine bit but this only returns the first phone number.

Comment: @Proveniebam sorry my friend, I'm not following you. What is the problem on the regex I provided you? Can you update the link I gave you with a non working example and send it to me?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting... it becomes more challenging when one considers phone numbers by name.  So many permutations are possible considering dashes, dots and parenthasis as delimiters.  Here is what I came up with:

```
((\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s\.\-]?\d{3}[\s\.\-]?\d{4})|(\+?\d{1,2}\s?\(?\-?\d{3}\)?\s?\-?[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,4}[\s\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,5}\b)
```

It seems to work OK for your example and several popular national numbers like 1-800-FLOWERS and 1 800 BEST-BUY, the latter of which was slightly tricky since the pattern is 4 letters - 3 letters instead of the reverse form.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Great answers guys.

Used: (0-9?)?((?[0-9]{3})?|[0-9]{3})( |-)?([0-9]{3}( |-)?[0-9]{4}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{7})*